# Progress 4GL Exclusive Lock Not Releasing

Tags: session, transactions, locking, progress-4gl

I'm using proserve to enable multiple-user session.
This is my code in a mouse double-click trigger on my browse:

```
  DO WITH FRAME MAIN-FRAME:
    IF EMP-BROWSE:NUM-SELECTED-ROWS > 0 THEN
    DO:
        EMP-BROWSE:FETCH-SELECTED-ROW(1).   
        FIND CURRENT EMPLOYEE NO-ERROR NO-WAIT.        
        IF AVAILABLE (EMPLOYEE) THEN
        DO:                 
            DO TRANSACTION ON ERROR UNDO, LEAVE:
                C-Win:SENSITIVE = NO.        
                FIND CURRENT EMPLOYEE EXCLUSIVE-LOCK.
                MESSAGE STRING(EMPLOYEE.emp-num) + " locked.".                    
                C-Win:SENSITIVE = YES.   
            END.    
            RELEASE EMPLOYEE.                     
        END.
        ELSE IF NOT AVAILABLE (EMPLOYEE) THEN
        DO:
            MESSAGE "The employee details is currently in-use in another session. Please try again later." VIEW-AS ALERT-BOX TITLE "System Message".
            RETURN NO-APPLY.
        END.
        ELSE
        DO:
            MESSAGE "The record has been deleted in another session.".    
            RETURN NO-APPLY.
        END.      
    END.
  END.
```

SCENARIO:

Session A double clicks on browse record 1. It will then message something like "2001 locked." after that Session B double clicks on browse record 1 and it will fire the message at the `IF NOT AVAILABLE (EMPLOYEE)` block.


My question is shouldn't the `RELEASE EMPLOYEE` code enable session B to access the same record? 


I have also tried `FIND CURRENT EMPLOYEE NO-LOCK` and putting either of the code inside and outside the `DO TRANSACTION` block but nothing happens.

EDIT:

I applied these changes but in the same scenario, Session B gets the message on the `ELSE` block which is `MESSAGE "The record has been deleted in another session.".` What am I doing wrong here? 

 When I add a call to a new window `RUN newWindow.w.` after `MESSAGE STRING(EMPLOYEE.emp-num) + "locked.".`, with the same scenario while not closing the new window on Session A I get a proper response of the record being used in another session in Session B.

```
DO WITH FRAME MAIN-FRAME:
    IF EMP-BROWSE:NUM-SELECTED-ROWS > 0 THEN
    DO:        
        EMP-BROWSE:FETCH-SELECTED-ROW(1).   
        FIND CURRENT EMPLOYEE NO-LOCK NO-ERROR NO-WAIT.        
        DEFINE VARIABLE iOk AS LOGICAL NO-UNDO.
        DEFINE BUFFER myEMPLOYEE FOR EMPLOYEE.
        iOk = NO.
        DO FOR myEMPLOYEE TRANSACTION:
        FIND myEMPLOYEE WHERE myEMPLOYEE.emp-num = EMPLOYEE.emp-num EXCLUSIVE-LOCK NO-ERROR NO-WAIT.
        IF AVAILABLE (myEMPLOYEE) THEN
        DO:
            IF LOCKED (myEMPLOYEE) THEN
            DO:
                MESSAGE "The employee details is currently in-use in another session. Please try again later." VIEW-AS ALERT-BOX TITLE "System Message".
                RETURN NO-APPLY.
            END.
            ELSE
            DO:
                C-Win:SENSITIVE = NO. 
                MESSAGE STRING(EMPLOYEE.emp-num) + " locked.". 
                C-Win:SENSITIVE = YES.   
            END.
        END.
        ELSE
        DO:
            MESSAGE "The record has been deleted in another session.".    
            RETURN NO-APPLY.
        END.
    END.
    END.
  END.
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have some things to reconsider here.

This row:

```
FIND CURRENT EMPLOYEE NO-ERROR NO-WAIT.
```

Will result in a SHARE-LOCK. Some people (including me) tend to avoid those. I would change into:

```
FIND CURRENT EMPLOYEE EXCLUSIVE-LOCK NO-ERROR NO-WAIT.
```

The row after:

```
IF AVAILABLE (EMPLOYEE) THEN
```

Will only deal with the existence of the record - not it's locking status. All in all, consider the online (F1) help:

> **LOCKED function**
>
> Returns a TRUE value if a record is not available to a prior FIND . . . NO-WAIT statement because another user has locked a record.
>
> **AVAILABLE function**
>
> Returns a TRUE value if the record buffer you name contains a record and returns a FALSE value if the record buffer is empty.
>
> **FIND...NO-ERROR**
>
> Suppresses ABL errors or error messages that would otherwise occur and diverts them to the ERROR-STATUS system handle. If an error occurs, the action of the statement is not done and execution continues with the next statement. If the statement fails, any persistent side-effects of the statement are backed out. If the statement includes an expression that contains other executable elements, like methods, the work performed by these elements may or may not be done, depending on the order the AVM resolves the expression elements and the occurrence of the error.
>
> **FIND...NO-WAIT**
>
> Causes FIND to return immediately and raise an error condition if the record is locked by another user (unless you use the NO-ERROR option on the same FIND statement). For example:

You could change this into (and the ELSE statement to something like):

```
FIND CURRENT EMPLOYEE EXCLUSIVE-LOCK NO-ERROR NO-WAIT.  

IF LOCKED(EMPLOYEE) THEN DO:
    MESSAGE "Locked by another user".
END.
ELSE DO:
    IF AVAILABLE (EMPLOYEE) THEN DO:
        MESSAGE "Go ahead and change".
    END.
    ELSE DO:
        MESSAGE "Not available".
    END.
END.
```

*Have in mind that you are writing code that's a mix between GUI, data access and business logic. This is a bad practice. You can do it for smaller examples, tests and things like that but you should actually avoid it. Even if you're not using AppServer right now you will most likely want to do that in the future - if the code already have nice separation of concern (for instance GUI, business logic and data access) future modernization will be so much easier.*

Comment: I applied the changes you suggested but unfortunately it didn't behave the way I want it to. It's still the same.

Comment: I've change my code and actually tested it this time instead of writing it from memory only...

Comment: I've redone my code as you specified. I get what your code means, it actually helped me understand how to know if a record is locked or not but the result is still the same. The exclusive-lock on the record buffer does not release. I've tried adding both `RELEASE EMPLOYEE` and `FIND CURRENT EMPLOYEE NO-LOCK` at the end of the `IF AVAILABLE (EMPLOYEE)` block. This is just a test project so regardless of how I code what's important is for it to work. Unfortunately this problem has been bugging me for weeks now.

Comment: Session A doesn't release or downgrade the lock so whenever Session B access the record it'll say that it's being used in another session. I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

RELEASE does not do what you think it does.  Use of RELEASE is a red flag.  It almost always means that the coder does not have a firm grasp of record and transaction scoping issues.

From the docs:

**RELEASE**

Verifies that a record complies with mandatory field and unique index definitions. It clears the record from the buffer and unites it to the database if it has been changed.

Notice how the definition says nothing about locks?

Embedding user interface within a transaction is a major mistake -- doing that essentially guarantees that you will have lock contention issues and scalability problems going forward.

As Jens points out your whole approach needs rethinking.

In order to properly control the record and transaction scope the best practice is to be very explicit about it and confine the update to a very tight block of code.  Ideally you encapsulate it in a procedure or function like so:

```
function updEmpName returns character ( input empNum as character, input newName as character ):

  define buffer employee for employee.

  do for employee transaction:
    find employee exclsuive lock where employee.employeeNum = empNum no-error.
    if locked employee then
      return "locked".
     else if available employee then
      do:
        assign
          employee.name = newName.
        .
        return "updated".
      end.
     else
      return "no such employee".
  end.
end.
```

If you cannot put the update in a function or procedure then you need to "strong scope" the buffer being used to update the record:

```
define variable ok as logical no-undo.
define buffer updEmployee for employee.

ok = no.

do for updEmployee transaction:
  find updEmployee exclusive-lock where updEmployee.employeeNum = empNum no-error.
  if available updEmployee then
    assign
      /* update whatever fields are needed */
      ok = yes
    .

end.
```

The "DO FOR updEmployee" is called "strong scope".  That means that there cannot be "free references" to the updEmployee buffer outside that block.  If the compiler complains that there is a problem then you need to fix it becuase your scope f not what you think it is.

Comment: I just updated my code, please check. For a strong scope I wouldn't need the `FIND CURRENT NO-LOCK` NOR `RELEASE BUFFERNAME` right?

Comment: I want to do the updating in another window, not inside a function so I guess a strong scope is best for this approach, please do correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: You are thinking about this all wrong "inside a window" makes no sense at all when speaking of transactions.

Comment: Nevermind what I said. With the current code I have, when I access the record on session A everything is working fine but when I access it on session B after session A it jumps to the `IF NOT AVAILABLE (EMPLOYEE)`. Shouldn't it be available since it is an existing record on the database? Locked or not locked records that exist should be in the `IF AVAILABLE (EMPLOYEE)` right?

Comment: I found out that when I access the same record on session b i get an unknown value for the AVAILABLE attribute of the buffer. It doesn't go to `IF AVAILABLE` and `IF NOT AVAILABLE` but instead it jumps to `ELSE`.

Answer (score 0):

The command `FETCH-SELECTED-ROW()` already put the selected record in browse into the record buffer using the LOCK that's defined within BROWSE definition, then you don't need to use a `FIND` statement to do so. Anyway, when I need to do things like you trying to do I use a code like this one :

```
DO WITH FRAME {&FRAME-NAME}:

    DO iCount = 1 TO brEmployee:NUM-SELECTED-ROWS:

        brEmployee:FETCH-SELECTED-ROW(iCount).
        IF AVAIL Employee THEN DO:

            FIND CURRENT Employee EXCLUSIVE-LOCK.
            /* Do whatever I need */
            FIND CURRENT Employee NO-LOCK.

        END.
        ELSE DO:

            IF LOCKED(Employee) THEN DO:
                MESSAGE 'Record locked!'
                    VIEW-AS ALERT-BOX INFO BUTTONS OK.
            END.
            ELSE DO:
                MESSAGE 'Record deleted!'
                    VIEW-AS ALERT-BOX INFO BUTTONS OK.
            END.

        END.

    END.

END.
```

In this example, the `FETCH-SELECTED-ROW()` aways return the record. If it isn't available you can check `LOCKED` condition. To avoid the browse to return records that doesn't exist in database you can use `-rereadnolock` session parameter.

But you're using the code within `MOUSE-SELECT-DBLCLICK` event of your browse. Then, you can replace the code with something like this :

```
DO WITH FRAME {&FRAME-NAME}:

    brEmployee:SELECT-FOCUSED-ROW() NO-ERROR.
    IF AVAIL Employee THEN DO:

        FIND CURRENT Employee EXCLUSIVE-LOCK.
        /* Do whatever I need */
        FIND CURRENT Employee NO-LOCK.

    END.
    ELSE DO:

        IF LOCKED(Employee) THEN DO:
            MESSAGE 'Record locked!'
                VIEW-AS ALERT-BOX INFO BUTTONS OK.
        END.
        ELSE DO:
            MESSAGE 'Record deleted!'
                VIEW-AS ALERT-BOX INFO BUTTONS OK.
        END.

    END.

END.
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Did you test this? It didn't work for me. The problem I'm facing now is that `FIND CURRENT Employee NO-LOCK.` isn't working or at least not how I want it to. Accessing the same record on a different session gives me an unknown value on the `AVAILABLE` attribute of the buffer instead of a logical YES or NO. See my comment on Tom Bascom's answer. Thanks.

Comment: @JohnEphraimTugado, this code works like a charm for me and I feel a little scared to hear that `AVAILABLE` function is returning an UNKNOWN value to you. The `AVAILABLE` function should not return this. Which version of OpenEdge are you using ?

Comment: I am using 10.1C I am checking the value of `AVAILABLE` with these code `IF AVAILABLE (buffer) ELSE IF NOT AVAILABLE (buffer) ELSE` and with accessing the same record on session B it jumps to `ELSE` so I assume it's not returning a logical `YES` or `NO`

Comment: Have you tried to write this logic in a separated .P file and call it through parameters from your .W (or .P, wherever you're using this) ?

Comment: I've tried this on two different procedure windows aside from my .W but it's still the same. Kinda sad really. Should I upgrade my version of Progress or this has nothing to do with it?

Comment: I think that upgrade your Progress version now isn't a good idea. Perhaps it can bring you more problems with another programs, problems that you don't have at this time and that - I'm sure about this - you don't want to have. So ... which is the exactly application of your program ? I mean ... what the purpose of your code for the end users ? Maybe we're focusing too much on something that can be solved using an workaround simpler than we're thinking ...

Comment: I just want my program to lock a record when double clicking on a browse row so that the user can edit it and release the lock after. In single user mode my code works like a charm but in multiple users mode it's not doing that good as you can see.

Comment: Right. I'll run some tests here and return to you as soon as possible. Sorry for the delay in response. I was out these days.